# Installing java 8:update-alternatives: error: alternative path /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0/bin/java doesn't exist

Tags: java, jdk, jre

I know this question might seem like a duplicate question, but I think its not. I'm trying to install java 8 on my ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I have tried many methods, but nothing worked for me. So I downloaded `jre-8u25-linux-x64.tar.gz`. Then I did the following:

```
tar -xvf jre-8u25-linux-x64.tar.gz 
sudo mkdir -p /usr/lib/jvm
sudo mv ./jdk1.8.0_25/ /usr/lib/jvm
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0/bin/java" 1
```

but I got the following error :

```
update-alternatives: error: alternative path /usr/lib/jvm/jdk/bin/java doesn't exist`
```

When I opened jdk1.8.0_25 I didn't find `bin/java` in it, so I re-downloaded it, but the same problem occurred.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

**EDIT**:

The output of : `update-alternatives --display java`

```
update-alternatives: warning: alternative /opt/jdk/jdk1.8.0_05/bin/java (part of link group java) doesn't exist; removing from list of alternatives
java - auto mode
  link currently points to /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/java
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java - priority 1071
  slave java.1.gz: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/man/man1/java.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/java - priority 1072
  slave java.1.gz: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/man/man1/java.1.gz
Current 'best' version is '/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/java'.
```

Comment: @the_Seppi actually it's not duplicate, I was following the answer of that question and I got this problem.

Comment: @the_Seppi I tried the easy way but I got an error, I don't remember it but I will retry it and post the error

Comment: What does `update-alternatives --display java` say? Please add this as an [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/568765/edit) to your question.

Comment: @the_Seppi check the edit please

Answer (score 1):

After you execute `sudo mv ./jdk1.8.0_25/ /usr/lib/jvm`, is the folder, 
`/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_25` created or `/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0` created?

```
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/usr/lib/jvm/**jdk1.8.0**/bin/java" 1
```

Answer (score 0):

From the below link :https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-manually-install-oracle-java-on-a-debian-or-ubuntu-vps

```
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/javac javac /opt/jdk/jdk1.8.0_05/bin/javac 100
```

Comment: I recommend that you **[edit]** this to expand it with an explanation of why you recommend that command. The link is useful, and you did include the command so this isn't *only* a link, which is good, but if you can summarize the important information about this as well, that would be helpful.

Comment: Actually, this solution works for me and I got that solution from that link.

Answer (score 0):

I had a folder `/usr/lib/java-8-openjdk-amd64`, so I made a symbolic link to it and named it `java-8-oracle`. It worked.